# How to build my react native app with TeamCity?

Tags: android, ios, docker, react-native, teamcity

I start using `Team City` and my app builds with `react native` `version 0.60.5`...

I was wondering what will be the best and the easier way to build my app for iOS and android.
For iOS I was thinking using the Xcode plug.

For android I'm thinking to use `Docker` but its complicated and taking time to develop..

Does someone has any recommendation what to use for building my android app or Docker is a good solution?

And about the iOS, are you recommend use the Xcode plug or any other idea?

Thank you for the help

Comment: someone has a solution?

Comment: Did you managed the app versionning through CI?

Answer (score 1):

You can easily use TeamCity to automatize your build for Android, check the official documentation for more [information](https://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/documentation/):

**You just need to be careful specifying the requirements for build your project for React Native, like:** 
version of react native, version of expo-cli, version of node that you are using in your project and etc...

For IOS, i recommend using fastlane, check this [official tutorial](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/tree/master/spaceship#2-step-verification) from Apple.
Don't forget that you need to have an developer account for build to ios in React-Native.